# Name of comment field differs on different sites

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template, comment-meta

I have a question regarding the „name“ of the comment field of wordpress blogs.
I have 2 sites, that are just available locally on my LAN.

On the first site, if I inspect the comment field in firefox, I see:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required="required"></textarea>
```

On the second site I see:

```
<textarea autocomplete="new-password" id="comment" name="i817ab2c85" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required="required" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Can anybody tell me, why the name of the comment field differs on the second site? Both sites have the same plugins installed and I didn't find an option to adjust the name or give it a random number. So I don't undrestand, why the comments on the second site are internally handled in such a strange way.

It would be nice, if I could adjust the name, to have unique identifiers for the comment field of each site - that's why I'm basically asking.

Greetings

Matse

Comment: It's impossible to say for certain with the information given, but if I had to guess the second site has some kind of security or anti-spam plugin which is attempting to obfuscate the comment forms.

Comment: Hello,
both sites just use AntiSpam Bee:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/antispam-bee/

That's why I'm so surprised. Both sides have nearly no plugins and are nearly identical. Do you know any plugin, that obfuscates the form?

Comment: I can see code in antispam-bee that does it.

Comment: Hmm stragen - I have the plugin installed on both sites with the same options.
Could it be, that Akismet was the cause of it? I had it activated on the first site, but uninstalled it quickly and replaced it with AntiSpamBee. Could it be, that Akismet changed something on the first site, which was not undone upon uninstalling?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Forget my last answers. You are absolutely right, Antispam Bee was the cause. I didn't install it on the second site. After installing it, I also have there now an obfuscated name.
Thanks so much for your help! I should have seen this myself.

Comment: @mathse please post the answer as an answer below so the site knows you've found your solution

Answer (score 1):

@JacobPeattie Forget my last answers. You are absolutely right, Antispam Bee was the cause. I didn't install it on the second site. After installing it, I also have there now an obfuscated name. Thanks so much for your help! I should have seen this myself.
Thanks for the great support here - with your help I could solve the problem within minutes!